# Does asp.net mvc use active or passive model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm reading about MVC pattern from the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx). In the article, the author specifies two kinds of model:

**Passive Model:**
Where the controller updates the model and eventually updates the view

**Active Model:**
Where the model and view implement observer pattern, so that change in model is notified to view.

When creating a Hello World ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I noticed that Controller calls **Controller.View()** and **Controller.View(model)** to return the view to the user. Does that mean it uses passive model? Also, it seems that model is always updated by the Controller, is it still MVC if View updates the model?

Comment: i would say its quite passive unless you are doing something like signalr with mvvm.

Comment: Downvoter, any reason why asking for clarifications is a bad idea and how I can make it better next time?

Comment: Unfortunately, for most of ASP.NET MVC applications, the answer is *"Neither, it users a collection of glorified active records"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct the common approach in MVC is passive model in most cases.

If you want to implement active model pattern ,you can use KnockoutJS in which ViewModels are in js and they update views when thier values change. Like observer pattern KnockoutJS have observables. See below example.

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro   (see step2 for observables)

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=933

Answer (score 2):

In the ASP.NET MVC - Model is passive, as controller simply passes model to View, and View gets data from current model by itself, i.e. Model cannot update data without controller.

WPF uses MVVM pattern - Model is active, as when data get changed, Model can send notification to the View and update data.

**Note:** If in the ASP.NET MVC you are using KnockoutJS or AngularJS, so, in this case, it's MVVM pattern.